# Eclipse no longer starts after installing Maven plugin: MetadataRepositoryManager not registered

Tags: eclipse, maven, repository, maven-plugin, startup

After installing the Maven plugin and closing Eclipse, I try to start Eclipse v8.3 I get an error referring me to a log file the configuration directory. (Contents below) This occurs even before  selecting a work space.

```
Root exception:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: MetadataRepositoryManager not registered.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.initializeMetadataRepository(RepositoryListener.java:115)
```

Googling MetadataRepositoryManager didn't turn up much...

After rebooting, the internet has suggested and I've tried (and reverted):

Specifying a full path to eclipse.p2.data.area in IBM\SDP\configuration\config.ini

Changing eclipse.product=com.ibm.rational.rft.product.ide to eclipse.product=org.eclipse.platform.ide in IBM\SDP\configuration\config.ini

Renaming: C:\Users[username].eclipse

Running: \IBM\SDP>.\eclipse.exe –clean

Changing the JRE to 1.6 from 1.7 in \IBM\SDP\eclipse.ini

Removing the workspace directories

Removing the configuration directory (led to a different issue: java error code=13)

Removing .snap file as suggested here: http://www.metod.si/job-found-still-running-after-platform-shutdown-eclipse/

None of these changes (now reverted) seemed to help.

Thank you in advance to any suggestions you might add.

Contents of LOG file:

```
!SESSION 2013-04-03 16:33:22.479 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.fullversion=JRE 1.7.0 IBM J9 2.6 Windows 7 x86-32 20120809_118929 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - R26_Java726_SR2_20120809_0948_B118929
JIT  - r11.b01_20120808_24925
GC   - R26_Java726_SR2_20120809_0948_B118929
J9CL - 20120809_118929
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product com.ibm.rational.rft.product.ide
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product com.ibm.rational.rft.product.ide

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins 4 0 2013-04-03 16:33:23.188
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: MetadataRepositoryManager not registered.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.initializeMetadataRepository(RepositoryListener.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.initialize(RepositoryListener.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.<init>(RepositoryListener.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.DropinsRepositoryListener.<init>(DropinsRepositoryListener.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.watchDropins(Activator.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.start(Activator.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    ... 12 more
Root exception:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: MetadataRepositoryManager not registered.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.initializeMetadataRepository(RepositoryListener.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.initialize(RepositoryListener.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.<init>(RepositoryListener.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.DropinsRepositoryListener.<init>(DropinsRepositoryListener.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.watchDropins(Activator.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.start(Activator.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.app 0 0 2013-04-03 16:33:23.392
!MESSAGE Product com.ibm.rational.rft.product.ide could not be found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-04-03 16:33:23.674
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-04-03 16:33:23.674
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:../../../Program Files (x86)/IBM/IBMIMShared/plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry_3.3.0.v20100520/ was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry 2 0 2013-04-03 16:33:23.674
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-04-03 16:33:23.706
!MESSAGE The following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-04-03 16:33:23.706
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry_3.3.0.v20100520 [378] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry 2 0 2013-04-03 16:33:23.706
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-04-03 16:33:23.706
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty_2.0.0.v20100503 [518] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-04-03 16:33:23.706
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.ui.win32_3.2.200.I20100509-0800 [726] was not resolved.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-04-03 16:33:23.709
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: No application id has been found.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilized solution: Re-install eclipse, make backups of directories before altering install.